# using inner join and 4 tables is that possible

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have a members table that   contain 3 field as a foreign key for 3 tables

so i want to join between them is that possible  ??

member table :

- governorate
- district
- village

each field is the foreign key for a table

governorate table :

- governorate_id
- governorat_name

district table :

- district_id
- district_name

village table :

- id
- village_name

can i do it in one query ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can.

```
SELECT  b.governorat_name,
        c.district_name,
        d.village_name
FROM    member a
        INNER JOIN governorate b
            ON a.governorate = b.governorate_id
        INNER JOIN district c
            ON a.district = c.district_id
        INNER JOIN village d
            ON a.village = d.id
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The query uses `INNER JOIN` in which results should have atleast one matching record on every parent table (`governorate`, `district`, `village`).

When columns are *nullable* and you want to show all records on table `member` table whether it has no matching record on the parent table, use `LEFT JOIN` instead if `INNER JOIN`.